# Counter-top garbage disposal switch: are there competing types, e.g. "air switch" vs something else?

Tags: switch, garbage-disposal, countertops

We need to replace our disposal but have never had one that was operated by a switch; we always used the twist-stopper style, which I recently learned is called a "batch" style disposal. For the new disposal, I am considering a counter-top-mounted switch. I want to find a switch that can be installed and forgotten about, and doesn't require adjustments or regular maintenance, since working under our corner sink is a real pain in the neck.

Are these counter-top-mounted switches all "air" activated via a tube that runs from the counter-top switch assembly over to the kit's outlet?

Comment: "counter top" is an air switch. But I think far more common is an ordinary toggle switch (i.e., same as a light switch) mounted on the wall above the counter/sink.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to the type of switch that is a [Button air  switch](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07HC83XDT) on the counter, then, yes.

These type of switches are very reliable, easy to install, ( save for the hole needed) and never need adjustment.

I have had one in my kitchen for over 8 years without any issues. They are safe, because your hand is never around anything electric and easy to keep clean. You should be very satisfied with an air activated switch.